# Customize themes not working

Tags: android, android-theme

i have to customize my whole application theme and i am trying to implement my custom theme.

i am able to implement custom theme but it is showing error when i apply it in manifest file.

here is my code for custome theme:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <!-- the theme applied to the application or activity -->
    <style name="CustomActionBarTheme"
           parent="@style/Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
    </style>

    <!-- ActionBar styles -->
    <style name="MyActionBar"
           parent="@style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar.Solid.Inverse">
        <item name="android:background">@drawable/actionbar_background</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

Comment: If you add your error log it will help us to identify the problem..

Comment: Also what is your min sdk in manifest?

Answer (score 0):

Change to

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <!-- the theme applied to the application or activity -->
    <style name="CustomActionBarTheme"
           parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
    </style>

    <!-- ActionBar styles -->
    <style name="MyActionBar"
           parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar.Solid.Inverse">
        <item name="android:background">@drawable/actionbar_background</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

In manifest apply theme as

```
 android:theme="@style/CustomActionBarTheme" >
```

Your min sdk in manifest should be 14. Use appcompact from the support library if you wish to support actionbar below api level 11.

Also check this

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html

https://developer.android.com/training/basics/actionbar/styling.html

Answer (score 0):

You should provide more details about the error you are getting. At first sight I can see you are using Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar, which I believe is only available for Android 4.x, so if you are targeting a previous version of Android you could get an error.

Try adding a style.xml file to each of the following folders:

```
res/values
res/values-v11
res/values-v14
```

Replace the referenced theme with Theme.Light in the style.xml file of the first folder. Use Theme.Holo.Light for v11 and leave Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar in the style.xml file under v14.

Also bear in mind you cannot style the action bar under versions prior to Honeycomb (v11). Check the [documentation for the ActionBar](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html) to get more details, in particular the information related to the AppCompat library.

I hope that helps. Otherwise, please provide more information about the error you are getting.

Answer (score 0):

```
<style name="CustomTheme" parent="android:Theme">
    <item name="android:windowTitleSize">35dip</item>
    <item name="android:windowTitleBackgroundStyle">@style/CustomWindowTitleBackground</item>
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">false</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/transparent</item>
</style>

<style name="CustomWindowTitleBackground">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/button_black</item>
</style>
```

put this code in style.xml and just change theme attribute of application tag in AndroidManifest.xml like

```
<application android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
     android:theme="@style/CustomTheme">
```

.

Thats it.